# pass the actual used factor combination (INDICES) to the inner function of a by clause / accessing the attributes of a by object

Tags: r

how do I access the actual used factor combination in a `by()` call?
I want to plot results from a dbscan (fpc-package) and add the corresponding factor combination to the plot title. The output is of class "by".
Using `attributes(res.lst)` respectively `attr(res.lst,"dimnames")` gives me only a global list . I cant map that to the individual used subset of data. So how does the `by` function "know" which combination is actual used for which subset. Where is this information stored?

I tried to make an easy example (skipping dbscan) to make it clear what the desired output should look like. Any help? I want to stick to base R if it's possible.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000), y=rnorm(1000), fac1=rep(c("L1", "L2"), 500), fac2= as.factor(c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5) )) ) # dummy data
# dummy plot function
fun.plot <- function(data, factorcomb=NA) { 
  if (is.na(factorcomb)==T) {
    ttl <- "Standard"
  } else { 
    ttl <- paste("factor combination: ", paste(factorcomb, collapse="+"))
  }
  dev.new()
  plot(data$x, data$y, main=ttl) 
}
res.lst <- by(data=dat, INDICES=dat[ ,colnames(dat[ , c(3,4)]) ], function(splt) fun.plot(splt) )

# desired result
for (f1 in levels(dat$fac1) ) {
  for (f2 in levels(dat$fac2) ) {
    fun.plot(dat[ which( dat$fac1==f1 & dat$fac2==f2), 1:2 ], factorcomb=c(f1,f2) )
   }
}
```

*EDIT:* This is the call from my original function.

```
 # by(data=adat, INDICES=adat[ ,colnames(adat[ ,c(36,41) ]) ], FUN=fun.dbscan, factornames=colnames(adat[ ,c(36,41) ]))
```

And the output on the coonsole looks like that:

```
PeakTemp: 250 # Factor 1 (column number 36) + Level
BGANr: BGA196_01 #Factor 2 (column number 41) + Level
dbscan Pts=1551 MinPts=12 eps=0.015
          0  1
seed      0 17
border 1534  0
total  1534 17
etc...
```

I want to pass actual used factor combination to the fun.dbscan function. In that case it would be PeakTemp with level 250 and BGANr BGA196_01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to what @joran did, but a bit different.

```
fun.plot <- function(data) {
  #change 3:4 if you have more variables
  factorcomb <- as.character(sapply(data[, 3:4], FUN = unique)) 
  ttl <- paste("factor combination: ", paste(factorcomb, collapse="+"))
  dev.new()
  plot(data$x, data$y, main=ttl) 
}
res.lst <- by(data = dat, INDICES = dat[ , 3:4], FUN = fun.plot)
```

*EDIT*

If you want to pass custom level names (e.g. `nms`), you can try using `mapply`. You can fiddle around to format `ttl` the way you want it, like replacing dot with a space.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000), y=rnorm(1000), fac1=rep(c("L1", "L2"), 500), fac2= as.factor(c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5) )) ) # dummy data
dat.split <- split(dat, dat[, 3:4])
nms <-names(dat.split)

fun.plot <- function(data, custom.names) {
  ttl <- paste("factor combination: ", custom.names)
  dev.new()
  plot(data$x, data$y, main=ttl) 
}
mapply(fun.plot, dat.split, nms)
```

Comment: Not sure if its intended but the result of the title does not depict the labels of the factors. Instead it outputs the "internal" factor level coded numerically.

Comment: @Sebastian Really? I get result, for example: "factor combination: L2+1". That's also how I see when I run your expected result bit.

Comment: Sorry, I rerun your code on an empty workspace. It works as you described. Maybe I changed something... Thanks for clarifying. Just to ask explicitly again: You don't know a way to pass the used factor combination explicitly? Basically my problem is solved but I am really surprised I don't get that working.

Comment: Yep, this exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. I sticked too much on `by`. Thanks. I suppose I overrated the possibilities of `by`. So I really need to take care of the split of the factor combinations by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're making this more complicated than you need to? Try something like this:

```
fun.plot <- function(data) { 
  ttl <- paste("factor combination: ", paste(unique(data$fac1),unique(data$fac2), sep="+"))
  dev.new()
  plot(data$x,data$y,main=ttl) 
}
res.lst <- by(data=dat, INDICES=dat[ ,colnames(dat[ ,c(3,4) ]) ], function(splt) fun.plot(splt) )
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the hint. I get it somehow working with that workaround. But this is not exactly convenient - I have many factors and I want to be flexible in adding and leaving it out but still want to add the information to the plot. Especially, if I take into account that `by`has the information ready in the output on the command line. I just need to grab that output and pass it inside the function. But I still don't know how can I do that?